# Disproving existence of a bijective map

Tags: functions, cardinals

Let $Maps(\mathbb N,\{0,1\})$ denote the set of all maps from $\mathbb N$ to $\{0,1\}$.
Prove that there does not exist any bijective map from $\mathbb N$ to $Maps(\mathbb N,\{0,1\})$.

The first thing that I thought of was to use proof by contradiction, but the problem is how do I deal with "$Maps(\mathbb N,\{0,1\})$"? I feel that I need to show that the cardinality of these 2 sets are different.

Any help or hints is seriously appreciated!

Comment: Have you heard of Cantor's diagonalization argument before?

Comment: Cantor's Theorem? Do I start off by taking the Power Set of Maps(N,{0,1})?

Comment: Did you answer my question with two questions? Don't you think that's annoying? Do you like it when people answer your questions with questions? Anyway, does this mean you *do* know Cantor's theorem or not?

Comment: Sorry about it, yes I do know what is Cantor's Theorem.

Comment: Great, then the answer I provide below should be what you need!

Comment: Working on it now, please pardon me for my bad reply, many thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to show that there *does* exist a bijection between $Maps(\mathbb N, \{0,1\})$ and $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$.

You can do this by looking at elements of $Maps(\mathbb N, \{0,1\})$ as indicator functions.

---

Alternatively, you could write a variant of Cantor's diagonal argument yourself.

Assume that there is a bijection. Then $Maps(\mathbb N,\{0,1\})=\{m_1,m_2,\dots\}$ where $m_i$ is a mapping from $\mathbb N$ to $\{0,1\}$.

Since $m_1$ is a mapping to $\{0,1\}$, we can represent it as, for example,

$$m_1 \equiv [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1\dots]$$

(this would mean $m_1(1)=0, m_1(2)=0, m_1(3)=1\dots$).

Now write down

$$m_1=[_1m_1, _2m_1,_3m_1\dots]\\
m_2=[_1m_2, _2m_2,_3m_2\dots]\\
m_3=[_1m_3, _2m_3,_3m_3\dots]\\\vdots$$

and you can (using a Cantor-like argument) construct a mapping $m$ that is not equal to any of the above mappings.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that there is bijection $\varphi\colon\mathbb N\to \operatorname{Maps}(\mathbb N,\{0,1\})$. Define $f\colon\mathbb N\to\{0,1\}$ with formula

$$f(n)=\begin{cases}
0,&\varphi(n)(n) = 1\\
1,&\varphi(n)(n) = 0\\\end{cases}.$$

Note that the idea behind $f$ is that $f(n) \neq \varphi(n)(n)$, for all $n$.

Since $\varphi$ is surjective, there exists some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $\varphi(n) = f$. But, then we have $$\varphi(n)(n)=f(n) \neq \varphi(n)(n)$$ which is contradiction. Hence, there is no bijection of $\mathbb N$ and $\operatorname{Maps}(\mathbb N,\{0,1\})$.

---

The argument above is called Cantor diagonal argument, and here is why. Functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\{0,1\}$ are sequences of $0$'s and $1$'s. So, a function $\varphi\colon\mathbb N\to \operatorname{Maps}(\mathbb N,\{0,1\})$ maps every natural number to a sequence of $0$'s and $1$'s. For example, $\varphi$ might look like

\begin{array}{ccccccc}
0,& 1,& 1,&0,&0,&1,&\ldots\\
0,& 1,& 0,&0,&0,&1,&\ldots\\
1,& 0,& 1,&1,&0,&0,&\ldots\\
0,& 1,& 0,&0,&1,&1,&\ldots\\
1,& 1,& 0,&1,&0,&1,&\ldots\\
0,& 0,& 1,&0,&0,&0,&\ldots\\
\vdots& \vdots& \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&
\end{array}

The idea is that if $\varphi$ is bijection, then all possible sequences are written in some row of the above table. Then, define $f$ as we did above. What is happening is that we are taking diagonal of the above table and change every $0$ to $1$ and every $1$ to $0$.

\begin{array}{cc}
{\begin{array}{ccccccc}
\color{blue}0,& 1,& 1,&0,&0,&1,&\ldots\\
0,& \color{blue}1,& 0,&0,&0,&1,&\ldots\\
1,& 0,& \color{blue}1,&1,&0,&0,&\ldots\\
0,& 1,& 0,&\color{blue}0,&1,&1,&\ldots\\
1,& 1,& 0,&1,&\color{blue}0,&1,&\ldots\\
0,& 0,& 1,&0,&0,&\color{blue}0,&\ldots\\
\vdots& \vdots& \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&
\end{array}} & {\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{diagonal} & 0,\ 1,\ 1,\ 0,\ 0,\ 0,\ \ldots\\\hline
f & 1,\ 0,\ 0,\ 1,\ 1,\ 1,\ \ldots
\end{array}}
\end{array}

Now, as we said, if $\varphi$ were bijection, then $f$ must be in the table. But, it can't be in the first row, because the first row is different from $f$ in the first place. It can't be in the second row since the second row is different from $f$ in the second place, etc. (This is what we wrote above as $f(n)\neq\varphi(n)(n)$, for all $n$.) Finally, we conclude that $f$ is not in the table, and hence we found a sequence that is not in the image of $\varphi$, so $\varphi$ can't be bijective.